# How can I delete Image from database from below code

Tags: javascript, php

I want to delete image from database when I click on No button ..

As there are multiple images in single row how this code will work for this ..

Single model popup shows the images when I click on its thumbnail and on Popup Model there is Yes and No button,

On "Yes" Button thumbnail should be as it is and no changes in database. 
But on "No" Button it should delete that particular image from database which is open in popup model.

Do I need to pass JavaScript variables to php code ?

```js
$(function popup() {
  $('.pop').on('click', function popup() {
   $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
   $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
  });  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<a href="#" class="pop">
    <img src="http://patyshibuya.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/04.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" class="img-responsive">
</a>
    
<a href="#" class="pop">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
</a>
<!-- Image Popup to large image  -->       
               
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" data-dismiss="modal">
    <div class="modal-content"  >              
      <div class="modal-body"><form action="#" method="POST">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
      </div> 
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <center>
        <div class="col-xs-12">Do you want to verify this? &nbsp;
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="yes">Yes</button> &nbsp; 
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="no">No</button>
          </div>
        </form>
          </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my php code .

```
if(isset($_POST['no'])) {
                $imagename = $_POST['imagename'];

 $update= "UPDATE usertable SET profile_image= NULL WHERE id='$id'";

                if(mysql_query($update)) {
                    echo "Successful!";
                    echo $imagename;
                } else {
                    echo mysql_error();
                }
            }
```

Comment: How does the database look? Like the rows and columns?

Comment: does update work instead of delete :-?

Comment: this is user profile database so there are profile image, id proof, and driving licence image, column present

Comment: change your query? its wrong in delete and update case

Comment: @sinaza yes, I have check some other post that suggest to use update query instead of delete..

Comment: @MayankVadiya I dont have problem with query. Yes above equation query may be wrong but I not able to update/delete (update image to NULL values as I need to verify ) particular image from database  which is open in Model after clicking on its thumbnail.

Comment: you need to use `unlink()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php if that's what the question is about.

Comment: as I said before there are more than one image and all images are in different folder .. and unlink will only work for single folder ..

Answer (score 1):

In your html make following changes:

```
<img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" id="deleteimage" >
```

And in your JS file add following code:

```
delete = $("#deleteimage").attr('src');
```

Then pass this "delete" value to your server using ajax.

```
your field in database "profile_image" what it actually contains. single image or multiple ?
```

Comment: this is user profile database so there are profile image, id proof, and driving licence image. 3 columns. How to pass delete to server .. ?

Comment: How can I delete particular image as there are different columns names can u write sql query